# how to make R parallel::parSapply run in absolute order of X?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

```
parSapply(cl = NULL, X, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE,
          USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

By default it will run in random order of X. But I would like it scheduled in order of X. 
is that possible?

Comment: I don't think it's exactly random. I have a hunch `X` is split into `number of cores used` chunks and run sequentially within each chunk.

Answer (score 1):

Scheduling in order of X is not directly possible. But there are multiple ways to get around this. One of the very easy way is to use **foreach** with the option

```
.inorder=TRUE
```

Giving a base example. Please change it based on your need

```
t <- foreach(x=X,.inorder=TRUE) %dopar % { FUN }
```